# Getting rubbish value when cout my dynamic array

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, memory, memory-management

Below is a snippet of my program

***Main function***

```
int main()
{
    ...

    int x_length = 0;
    int * mapX = new[x_length];
    functionA(x_length, mapX);

    ...
    delete[]mapX;
}
```

***Function A***

```
void functionA(int &x_length, int *&mapX)
{
    ...
    int x_pos = 0;
    int x_length_functionA = 0; // declare internal variable

    ...

    for(int i=0; i <= 8; i++)
    {
        ++x_length_functionA;
    }

    int * mapX_functionA = new int[x_length_functionA];

    for(int i = 0; i < x_length_functionA; i++)
    {
        mapX_functionA[x_pos++] = i;
    }

    x_length = x_length_functionA; // x_length_functionA is 9
    mapX = mapX_functionA;
    
    ...
    delete[]mapX_functionA;
}
```

When I `cout` the `mapX_functionA` array inside `functionA`, the array output is correct that is:

***Correct cout inside functionA***

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
```

When I cout in my main function on `mapX`, I get some rubbish first value that is

***Incorrect cout in main function***

```
157306016 // this is suppose to be 0!
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
```

I am quite sure this could be due to memory fault somewhere.

I thought I have did everything right - the `mapX` is pass by reference in the function declaration, and I copy the `mapX_functionA` to `mapX` will work. When I check `x_length` in `main`, it output the correct integer.

Why is the first array getting this rubbish value?

P.S: Before anyone ask why I didn't use vector, this is for educational and knowledge purpose.

Comment: Both of your allocations allocate array of length `0`, how many elements do you think you can access?

Comment: *Before anyone ask why I didn't use vector, this is for educational and knowledge purpose.* -- Better to see how a simple vector class is implemented, rather than trial and error approaches.

Comment: Edited my post to answer your question. There is a `for loop` which I did not include that `++` the `x_length_functionA`.

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: The loop `for(int i = 0; i <= x_length_functionA; i++)` has [off-by-one error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error).

Comment: It seems the argument `int x_length` should also be a reference.

Comment: I don't understand why the loop will have a off-by-one-error for `for(int i = 0; i <= x_length_functionA; i++)`, the end result contains 9 integers from 0 to 8.

Comment: Not only that, the function has memory leaks.  Where is the `delete[]` call to deallocate the old memory?

Comment: Off by one error here `for(int i = 0; i <= x_length_functionA; i++)`, it should be `for(int i = 0; i < x_length_functionA; i++)`. If an array has size `N` the value indexes are from `0` to `N - 1`

Comment: Now your latest edit made it worse.  You are now deallocating the array you just allocated and assigned to `mapX`.

Comment: And the off by one error is still there.

Comment: Double check against my program, and my actual program `for loop` do not consist of the `<= x_length_functionA` and it is `<` instead, it was my mistake in the post. But the issue still persist with the first rubbish value shown in `main`.

Comment: Off by one fixed but you are still deallocating the wrong memory. Do it like this `delete[] mapX; mapX = mapX_functionA;`

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> mapX = mapX_functionA;
> ```

On this line, you make `mapX` point to same array as `mapX_functionA`.

> ```
> delete[]mapX_functionA;
> ```

On this line, you delete the array pointed by `mapX_functionA` and `mapX`. All pointers to the array become invalid.

> Incorrect cout in main function

You failed to show what you are printing, but it is my assumption that you indirect through `mapX` which is now invalid, and therefore the behaviour of your program is undefined.

You also later delete this invalid pointer on the last line of `main`:

> ```
> delete[]mapX;
> ```

Which also has undefined behaviour.

---

P.S. You leak the allocation that you make on this line:

> ```
> int * mapX = new[x_length];
> ```

because that pointer value is overwritten on line

> ```
> mapX = mapX_functionA;
> ```

You also failed to declare the variable that you assign on line:

> ```
> x_length_functionA = 0;
> ```

Comment: Thanks eeorika. `x_length_functionA` declaration is a mistake when I type the code (actual program works for this variable). `mapX_functionA` is meant to copy its data into `mapX` so that I can use this `mapX` in other functions in `main`. To handle memory leak, am I not suppose to just use `delete` at every places with `new`?

Comment: @user3118602 You're supposed to delete before you lose the pointer value. And you're supposed to not delete same pointer value multiple times. And you're supposed to not indirect through a pointer value after it has been deleted.