# Dynamically allocated array not copying correctly

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, memory, memory-management

I have the following reproducible example

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void printArray(int *data, int x)
{
    for(int v = 0; v < x; v++)
        cout << data[v] << endl;
}

void functionA(int &x_length, int &y_length, int *&x_array, int *&y_array);

int main()
{
    int x_length = 0;
    int y_length = 0;
    int * x_array = new int[x_length];
    int * y_array = new int[y_length];
    functionA(x_length, y_length, x_array, y_array);
    
    cout << "x length : " << x_length;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "y length : " << y_length;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "x array" << endl;
    printArray(x_array, x_length);
    
    cout << endl;
    cout << "y array" << endl;
    printArray(y_array, y_length);

    delete [] x_array;
    delete [] y_array;
}

void functionA(int &x_length, int &y_length, int *&x_array, int *&y_array)
{
    int x_length_functionA = 0;
    int y_length_functionA = 0;
    int x_increment = 0;
    int y_increment = 0;
    
    // Create array x
    for(int i = 3; i <= 8; i++)
    {
        ++x_length_functionA;
    }
    
    int * x_array_functionA = new int[x_length_functionA];
    
    for(int i = 3; i <= 8; i++)
    {
        x_array_functionA[x_increment++] = i;
    }
    
    x_length = x_length_functionA;
    x_array = x_array_functionA;
    
    // Create array y
    for(int i = 3; i <= 10; i++)
    {
        ++y_length_functionA;
    }
    
    int * y_array_functionA = new int[y_length_functionA];
    
    for(int i = 3; i <= 10; i++)
    {
        y_array_functionA[y_increment++] =i;
    }
    
    y_length = y_length_functionA;
    y_array = y_array_functionA;
    
    delete []x_array_functionA;
    delete []y_array_functionA;
    
}
```

Output result (printArray in main())

```
x length : 6                                                                                                                                                                                  
y length : 8    
                                                                                                                                                                          
x array                                                                                                                                                                                       
0                                                                                                                                                                                             
0                                                                                                                                                                                             
5                                                                                                                                                                                             
6                                                                                                                                                                                             
7                                                                                                                                                                                             
8                                                                                                                                                                                             
                                                                                                                                                                                              
y array                                                                                                                                                                                       
0                                                                                                                                                                                             
0                                                                                                                                                                                             
5                                                                                                                                                                                             
6                                                                                                                                                                                             
7                                                                                                                                                                                             
8                                                                                                                                                                                             
9                                                                                                                                                                                             
10
```

The expected result (printArray in main())

```
x length : 6                                                                                                                                                                                  
y length : 8    
                                                                                                                                                                          
x array                                                                                                                                                                                      
3                                                                                                                                                                                             
4                                                                                                                                                                                             
5                                                                                                                                                                                             
6                                                                                                                                                                                             
7                                                                                                                                                                                             
8                                                                                                                                                                                             
                                                                                                                                                                                              
y array                                                                                                                                                                                       
3                                                                                                                                                                                             
4                                                                                                                                                                                             
5                                                                                                                                                                                             
6                                                                                                                                                                                             
7                                                                                                                                                                                             
8                                                                                                                                                                                             
9                                                                                                                                                                                             
10
```

When I `printArray` in `functionA()`, the array printed the expected result that I want. When I copy `x_array_functionA` to `x_array` and `printArray` in `main`, the output result was not what I am expected. The first two values are always zero.

Why is the initial integers not getting copy over?

Note: This is a follow-up to [Getting rubbish value when cout my dynamic array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62995195/getting-rubbish-value-when-cout-my-dynamic-array). Created a new question as I feel that the initial question is not clear without a proper reproducible example. Also understand that there are probably memory leaks in the code.

Comment: You `delete[]` your arrays at the end of `functionA`....

Comment: @ChrisMM Ah! Now I finally see it. What is a proper way to deallocate my memory for the `new` in `functionA`?

Comment: Your bug is here `delete []x_array_functionA; delete []y_array_functionA;` Note that the = operator before these deletes `y_length = y_length_functionA; y_array = y_array_functionA;`  just assigns the pointers to point to the same memory.

Comment: @churill In the actual program, `x_array` and `y_array` are user input range during run time, therefore there is no fixed array length.

Comment: using `std::vector` would simplify code.

Comment: And there that is.

Comment: @user3118602 That's good, but you may want to make a comment there or remove the initialization alltogether. It's a potential error there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know that this is all the errors, but at the end of the `functionA`, you have:

```
delete []x_array_functionA;
delete []y_array_functionA;
```

Use of the arrays after this is UB. In order to properly clean up memory, when you do

```
x_array = x_array_functionA;
```

You should be doing

```
delete[] x_array;
x_array = x_array_functionA;
```

Same for the `y_array`.

Comment: Thanks Chris. To confirm my understand, this means prior to copying `x_array_functionA` over, I will need to deallocate `x_array` first to avoid memory leak. Then `x_array_functionA` will copy to `x_array` with a new allocated set of memory? Should I `delete [] x_array_functionA` somewhere in this example?

Comment: `x_array = x_array_functionA` doesn't _copy_ anything. It changes where `x_array` is pointing to. After this line, `x_array` now points to the memory allocated for `x_array_functionA`. This, therefore, means that `x_array_functionA` should **not** be `delete[]`ed. It is handled by the `delete[] x_array;` at the end of your `main` method.

Comment: Clear explanation, thanks for helping a C++ newbie!

Answer (score 2):

Here:

```
delete [] x_array_functionA;
delete [] y_array_functionA;
```

you delete the arrays. After this point, the arrays have been deleted. Accessing them is undefined behaviour. Deleting them *twice* (because they are *also* deleted in `main`) is definitely undefined behaviour.

Remember that you don't delete pointers, you delete things you allocated. The fact that one time you use a variable called `x_array` to delete the array, and one time you use a variable called `x_array_functionA` to delete the array, is completely irrelevant - either way, you delete the same array twice.

Your code also never deletes the arrays allocated in `main`.